# AngularJS promise chain

Tags: angularjs, promise, chain

I have my application that should open a popup ask a confirmation at the user, then make an ajax cal and close the popup.
I tried to do it using a chain of *promise* (I've already used it, and I remember that it should work in this way), but it seems to block after the call to`reservationService.confirm($scope.object);`. Now it is a fake service implemented with a `setTimeout` and `$q` just to return a promise (in future it will make the ajax call). Is this a valid code or I didn't undestood how promise works?
For the popup I choose AngularUI and the code is this:

```
 reservationService.book($scope.object, day)
        .then(function(){
            var dialogOpts = {/* dialog options omitted*/}
            return $dialog.dialog(dialogOpts).open();

        })
        .then(function(result){
            console.log('confirmed? ', result);
            if (result){
                //After this line it doesn't do nothing, also if the promise is resolved 
                return reservationService.confirm($scope.object);
            }
        })
        .then(function(){
            //this function is never executed
            $scope.$emit('object:detail',{object: $scope.object});
        });
```

reservationService:

```
function confirm(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     setTimeout(function(){
          console.log('Confirming');
          deferred.resolve(true)
     }, 500);
     return deferred.promise;
}
```

**SOLVED**
change `setTimeout` with `$timeout` angular's service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Used `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` 'cause it works togheter at the angular scope, forcing the `digest` phase (or use `$scope.apply()` inside the `setTimeout`).

Answer (score 2):

Can you try

```
//skipping the first then
.then(function(result){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            console.log('confirmed? ', result);
            if (result){
                //After this line it doesn't do nothing, also if the promise is resolved 
                return deferred.resolve(reservationService.confirm($scope.object));
            }
            deferred.resolve();
            return deferred.promise;
        })
.then(function(){
                //this function is never executed
                $scope.$emit('object:detail',{object: $scope.object});
            });
```

For chaining then, the last then success or failure function should return a promise. As the `$q` [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) mentions

> then(successCallback, errorCallback) – regardless of when the promise
>   was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or
>   error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The
>   callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection
>   reason.
>
> This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via
>   the return value of the successCallback or errorCallback.

Comment: In this way it works, but it is at the same way the `reservationService` works...

Comment: I don't get what you mean to say?

Comment: I was editing the post...look now there is the implementation of the `confirm` method. It is implemented at the same way you did...but why I have to call the `deferred.resolve` passing in it the `promise` returned from the service, when it is resolve from the `setTimeout`?

Comment: `reservationService` returns a promise so you can call `then` on it. This `then` again returns a promise that is resolved by `return $dialog.dialog(dialogOpts).open();` (internally i think) hence the next chained `then` gets called. The second `then` **does** return promise but there is no call to resolve it, and hence the next then never gets executed.

Comment: ahah no..the problem was something with the `setTimeout` that doesn't call some phase of angular, in fact, now I changed the `setTimeout` with `$timeout` and it works correctly, with my code. Promise `then` method should return a `promise` and doesn't have to `resolve` it.