# AngularJS : promise chain not deferring past 2nd function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred, angular-promise

as an extension [of a question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868388)  (thanks for all the help!),
I'm having trouble getting my 2nd returned promise working (in a chain of 3 or more)
I've check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605881/chaining-promises-in-angularjs), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484986/angularjs-promise-chain) but can't get any clues to my current code

app and controller look like:

```
myApp.controller('Controller_1', function($scope, myService) {

    var myName = "Ben";

    myService.slowService(myName)
    .then(function(result){myService.slowService2(result);})
    .then(function(result){myService.fastService(result);});

    $scope.myName = myName;
});
```

service provider looks like:

```
myApp.service('myService', function($q, $timeout) {

    this.slowService = function (name) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log('Start of slowService1:', name, Date.now());

        $timeout(function() {
            name = 'Hello, ' + name + " is learning Angularjs";
            alert(name); 
            deferred.resolve(name);
                console.log('End of slowService1 timeout:', name, Date.now());
        }, 1500);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.slowService2 = function (name) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log('Start of slowService2:', name, Date.now());

        $timeout(function() {
            name = 'Hello, ' + name + " is learning Angularjs";
            alert(name); 
            deferred.resolve(name);
                console.log('End of slowService2 timeout:', name, Date.now());
        }, 1000);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.fastService = function(name){ 
        var deferred = $q.defer();
            console.log('Start of fastService:', name, Date.now());
        alert('Hello ' + name + ' - you are quick!'); 
        deferred.resolve();
            console.log('End of fastService:', name, Date.now());
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

Console output looks like:

```
Start of slowService1: Ben 1420877247858
End of slowService1 timeout: Hello, Ben is learning Angularjs 1420877250982
Start of slowService2: Hello, Ben is learning Angularjs 1420877250983
Start of fastService: undefined 1420877250984
End of fastService: undefined 1420877251641
End of slowService2 timeout: Hello, Hello, Ben is learning Angularjs is learning Angularjs 1420877254148
```

So while the 1st `slowService1` $q.defer() works, the 3rd function `fastService` doesn't wait for the 2nd `slowService2` deferred object to resolve prior to starting...  ?

jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/bowsyydv/)

PS $timeout is only to simulate $http calls and SQLite queries etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `return` the promise such that you could chain with `.then`:

```
myService.slowService(myName)
    .then(function(result){
        return myService.slowService2(result);
     })
    .then(function(result){
        myService.fastService(result);
     });
```

Comment: seriously, you folks are the best !

Comment: Thanks for the complement, but it's customary on SO to upvote and accept the most helpful answer

Comment: sure was waiting for the 15 minutes and got distracted applying the solution to my code :-) done. ...while we're here can you tell me the difference between `return` in the `.then` and `return deferred.promise;` within the service functions ?  I thought I was already returning the promise _with_ the deferred object ?

Comment: But you then have to return that promise from within the anonymous function of `.then`.